# UnGzip and Untar inputStream

Tags: java

i'm trying to unGzip and unTar an inputStream in java , i have those methods :

```
public InputStream unTar(InputStream in) throws IOException {

    TarInputStream myTarStream = new TarInputStream(in);
    TarEntry entry = myTarStream.getNextEntry();
    InputStream input = null;
    while (entry != null) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        do {
            read = myTarStream.read(buff);
            if (read != -1) {
                output.write(buff, 0, read);
            }
        } while (read != -1);
        output.flush();
        input = new ByteArrayInputStream(output.toByteArray());
        entry = myTarStream.getNextEntry();
    }
    myTarStream.close();

    return input;
}

public InputStream unGzipIt(InputStream in) {

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    InputStream outGZIPStream = null;
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytesOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        GZIPInputStream gis = new GZIPInputStream(in);
        int len;
        while ((len = gis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            bytesOutput.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
        in.close();
        bytesOutput.close();
        outGZIPStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytesOutput.toByteArray());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return outGZIPStream;
}
```

the problem is when i passed an inputStream from a file in my local , it working,
but when i passed the inputStream from my server response , it doesn't work .

should i use reset and mark ? any help ? thank you

this i s how i'm getting the inputStream :

```
 public InputStream getFolder(@PathParam("id") String envId, @PathParam("appName") String appName, @PathParam("imageType") String imageType,
                                 @QueryParam("folderPath") String folderPath) throws EnvAutomationException, IOException {
        Environment env = Envs.getEnvironmentManager().findEnvironment(envId);
        ApplicationInstance appInst = env.getApplicationInstance(appName);
        Container container = appInst.getContainer(imageType);
        InputStream folderData = Envs.getContainerizationManager().getFolder(container, folderPath);
        ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
        int size = 0;
        int read;
        do {
            read = folderData.read(buff);
            if (read != -1) {
                size = size + read;
                output.write(buff, 0, read);
            }
        } while (read != -1);
        output.flush();
        byte[] bo = output.toByteArray();
        InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(bo);
        InputStream inputGZIP = gzipIt(input);
        return inputGZIP;
    }
```

since it's a .tar file , i gizip it and this is the method to gzip;

```
 public InputStream gzipIt(InputStream source) {

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        InputStream outGZIPStream = null;
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytesOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            GZIPOutputStream gzos = new GZIPOutputStream(bytesOutput);
            int len;
            int size = 0;
            while ((len = source.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                gzos.write(buffer, 0, len);
                size = size + len;
            }
            source.close();
            gzos.close();
            byte[] bo = bytesOutput.toByteArray();
            outGZIPStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytesOutput.toByteArray());
            logger.info("folder tar size :" + size +  " ; folder gzip size  " + bo.length);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return outGZIPStream;
    }
```

Comment: Unrelated note: consider to use try-with-resources to close your streams.

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: Please provide the relevant part of the stack-trace.

Comment: it is necessary the stack-trace? no more information than NullPointerException, but maybe because the Inputstream is coming from the server , so i have to  BufferedInputStream so i can do the reset and mark

Comment: Well the question is: which object reference was null and where was it called?

Comment: the imputStream that i'm givin it as a parameter

Comment: So then there is the problem. Show us how you're getting this input stream.

Comment: "_it is necessary the stack-trace?_" Yes. It gives you more info than just that the error was an NPE. It will also tell you which line the error occurred on. With that we can direct you to the exact problem.

Comment: but i'm getting the inputstream as an .tar.gz from the server and i can put it in an FTP server , but i cannot ungzip